# how to set conditional css in php

Tags: php, mysql, vba, excel

this scripts reads and excel file and put them into a table and show them . the problem here is i want my data in cell to show green if they are above 0 and red if they are less than 0 this is my script and i dont know why it doesnt work !! every thing is fine untill line 53 !!wich i set if for val above 0 !! can any one help ?? thnkx in advance !!!

`

```
  <?php
    require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","datanew","datanew");
mysql_select_db("datanew",$conn);

$path = "1.xlsx";

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;

    echo '<table><tr>';
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue();
            $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
            echo '<td>' . $val . '<br></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    $val=array();
for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
   $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
   $val[] = $cell->getValue();
} }
?>
<?php

    if($val > 0) {?>
       <td style="color:#06e716;"></td>
    <?php } else { ?>
     <td style="color:#e70630;"></td>
<?php } ?>`
```

Comment: And line 53 is what? Your example does not have even 53 rows..

Comment: sorry !! my bad !! by line 53 i mean  the last if statement at the end of the script that i added to set conditonal css for table data !! Apologies

Comment: I see that in the last few lines you have an array $val. But then in your if you check if $val > 0. What do you expect that to do? array() > 0 ??? Well, yes, an array with values is > 0. But that doesn't really mean anything. So the question is really: what is it you're trying to base your conditional on?

Comment: Your color logic is completely separate from the "display the values" logic. What you're doing is not possible. You need do move the `if ($val) { green }` logic up to where you have the `echo '<td>'` stuff.

Comment: hmmm !!i want to set condition on table values ! wich i thought That $val in this script !!

Comment: thnkx marc that was the thing i didnt notice !! i try to fix code to see if it work !! but just can u please tell me where exactly to add the if statement ?? after echo ing the td ? or before that ?? or even inside :) (if possible )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$val` is an array, you need to use `count` function

try

```
if(count($val)>0){

}else{

}
```

Comment: there are more problems: he is also iterating over the same sheet TWICE, showing it TWICE. Once inside a table, and once... right after the table... which is just bad HTML.

Comment: Again no result on adding count. i found this script on stackoverflow and it works fine for showing excel on browser and just one time in table if i get you right !!